# Arch based system hangs on systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot, hang

my EndeavorOS (arch based) install has worked fine for months before randomly shutting down and now it hangs on systemd `[OK] Reached target System Time Set`
I've tried updating the system through chroot to see if it was since I hadn't updated in a while, and I've tried using the systemd debug console which didn't even show up.
I'm using EndeavorOS (arch based), Grub, XFCE
I'm fairly new to Linux, and sorry if this isn't descriptive enough, not sure what exactly to add.
EDIT:
after some help from @telometto i have these pastebins with some results from commands they said to use.
pastebin.com/aQqpZX1A - `grep -i upgraded /var/log/pacman.log`
pastebin.com/himpZYGm - `journalctl -p 3 -xb`

Comment: Have you checked the logs? What's the output of `journalctl -b -1 -r`? Also, does hitting `Ctrl + C` allow the shutdown to proceed?

Comment: huh? this is an issue with it starting up to begin with, not shutting down. Ctrl+c does nothing

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I misread, then; I thought the system hung on shutdown. So the system hangs on startup? Can you check the logs for any errors or warnings (`journalctl -p 3 -xb`)? Does it let you enter to the desktop at all?

Comment: the command you gave `journalctl -p 3 -xb` returns `-- No entries --`, and no, it stops doing anything before it loads the desktop

Comment: Ok. Try with `4` instead of 3. Also, are you getting to the logs through a `chroot`? Have you tried booting directly into `tty` from grub?

Comment: oh wait, i ran the command through a chroot since i was using it to try something and i forgot to exit. the command `journalctl -p 3 -xb` actually returns a few entries, here's a pastebin with the journals
https://pastebin.com/himpZYGm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142046/discussion-between-telometto-and-sephistius-rune).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar issues with systemd and XFCE I stopped using the XFCE environment as much as I liked it and switched to a new DE. Other alternatives that come to mind are MSConfig, OpenRC, runict and s6 which are basically boot managers, I don't  recommend playing around with grub as a newbie you can brick your system, If your Linux machine is your daily driver, as mine is can I suggest Garuda Linux it is Arch Based and systemd runs seamlessly on it.